# Why is my onclick event not being triggered?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React for an app which has a Google login which redirects to a simple page that has a side bar and a navbar with a logout button. For some reason when I click on my logout button the onclick event is not triggering my function which updates a state and produces a logout.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { LoginProvider } from './LoginContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <LoginProvider >
      <App />
    </LoginProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './atoms/Login';
import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import LoginContext from './LoginContext';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import Search from './pages/Search';
import Main from './templates/Main';

function App() {
  const {isLoggedIn} = useContext(LoginContext);
  console.log(isLoggedIn);
  return (    
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={isLoggedIn ? <Main/> : <Login />}/>
        <Route path="/contact" element ={<Contact/>}/> 
        <Route path="/search" element ={<Search/>}/>       
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>   
    );
}

export default App;
```

When a user is logged in, the app renders the `<Dashboard/>` component.

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../organisms/Sidebar'
import './Dashboard.css'
import LoginContext from '../LoginContext'; 

const Dashboard = () => {

  const {user} = useContext(LoginContext);
  console.log(user)

  return (
    <div className='dashboard'>
      <div className="user-content">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
        <div className='content'>
            <h1>Welcome to my Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Dashboard component has a sidebar which only contains links in it.

Main.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard'
import Navbar from '../organisms/Navbar'

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Dashboard />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

The component above renders the dashboard and the navbar. The issue now is at the navbar.

The `<Navbar/>` component has user data and a logout button that are being brought from a context.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import LoginContext from '../LoginContext';
import LogoutBtn from '../atoms/LogoutBtn';
import './Navbar.css';


const Navbar = () => {

  const {user, handleSignOut} = useContext(LoginContext);  

  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
        <div className="userInfo">
            <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="logout">
            {
            //If user objetc is not empty show sign out button
                Object.keys(user).length !== 0 &&
                <LogoutBtn onClick={(e)=>handleSignOut(e)}/>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

And this is the context where the logic is.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';


const LoginContext = createContext();

export function LoginProvider({ children}) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({}) 
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    

    function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        var userData = jwt_decode(response.credential); //Token with the login user Data
        setUser(userData); //Store user Data 
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = true;
            
      }

    function handleSignOut(event) {
        setUser({}) //Empy the user Data
        setIsLoggedIn(false)        
        
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = false;
    }  

    return(
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut, isLoggedIn}}>{children}</LoginContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default LoginContext
```

Here I have the function handleSignOut which takes an event and as the function is being called, the state of setIsLogged in is updated to false and makes the user to logout. For some reason yesterday my button was working perfectly fine but now as I click on the sign out button nothing happens.

Comment: Are all consumers of LoginContext below the Context Provider component?

Comment: It looks like App will have to be below < LoginProvider >

Comment: @windowsill it is, my bad i didnt paste my index.js where i have `<LoginProvider>` wrapping `<App>`

Comment: @mateoghidini what are you expecting to see after you log out?

Comment: I already solved it. It wasnt working because i made a new component just for the logout button and i forgot to pass props. @yousoumar